# This function is a multiple of the identity function

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a derivable function such that every tangent lines of its graph intersect the origin. I would like to know how to prove that $f$ is a multiple of the identity function.

It seems easy, but I've already tried to use the definition of derivative and I couldn't take any information about this function.

I need a hint to solve this question.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The tangent line through the point $(a,f(a))$ will be $y=f'(a)x$ since $f'(a)$ is the slope of the tangent line through $(a,f(a))$ and since the $y$-intercept is $0$. On the other hand we must have $f(a)=f'(a)a$ so $af'(a)-f(a)=0$. Notice that this is true for all $a$ so:

$\frac{d}{da}\big(\frac{f(a)}{a}\big)=\frac{af'(a)-f(a)}{a^{2}}=0$

So $f(a)=Ca$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** the tangent point to the graph at $x$ will pass through the origin for each $x$ if and only if 
$$
f'(x) = f(x)/x \implies f'(x)/f(x) = 1/x \implies [\ln(f(x))]' = [\ln(x)]'
$$